# Getting a probable logic error with an array method

Tags: arrays, sorting, methods, return, double

While practising my method making I came across this error:
"[D@33909752"

I want to make the code as simple as possible so I also have another question other than how to fix that error: Can I somehow put Scanner and the input variables in the `displaySortedNumbers` method? Possibly in the end id like to only have to do something like:

```
System.out.print(displaySortedNumbers(a, b, c));
```

And have them already sorted.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumSorter {

    public static double[] displaySortedNumbers(double num1, double num2, double num3) {

        double[] numbers = {num1, num2, num3};
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        return numbers;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter 3 numbers to be sorted in assending order: ");
        double a = in.nextDouble();
        double b = in.nextDouble();
        double c = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print(displaySortedNumbers(a, b, c));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print an array you will get the reference to that array that may look like `"D@33909752"`. That's expected and not an error. You probably want to print the elements of the array. In that case change you last line like this :

```
double[] result = displaySortedNumbers(a, b, c); 
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Regarding your other question, your code could be quite simpler by writing directly to the array, instead of a,b,c. E.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    double[] numbers = new double[3];
    System.out.print("Enter " + numbers.length + " numbers to be sorted in assending order: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = in.nextDouble();
    }

    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```

Note how copying is avoided. And if you want to have the user input more numbers you have to change your code at only one place. You can consider refactoring to move any part of that to another function.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me alot.

Comment: @Alex in StackOverflow you indicate that an answer was helpful by upvoting and / or accepting the answer. You post a comment if the answer is unclear / incomplete / incorrect etc I am happy to help anyway!